# Show Sprites on Overlap (Shader Graph) [2D]

Tags: unity, 2d, shaders, mesh, unity-shader-graph

[image]

I have a character sprite mesh and mesh renderer (The black wavy box). I am hoping to be able to overlay the black box onto the character covering the sprites but I am not sure how to do that.

I looked at this question : [Unity: How do I only show parts of objects that overlap [2D]](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/162755/unity-how-do-i-only-show-parts-of-objects-that-overlap-2d?newreg=59a379c85ad0450eaa2fc772839c7cf1)

But this works more as a cover that you can see through. I am hoping to have the variable black mask the sprites of the character but I cant seem to layer these correctly. Is there a way to do this using the LWRP and shader graph?

The over arching idea is to use this as a damage marker. Moving the black box up or down depending on the health lost.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little trickier to achieve than it looks, because each part of a sprite - by the time it reaches the GPU - is just a lone triangle that knows nothing about the other triangles in the scene, including the positions & sizes of other sprites.

So, we have to fake it a little. We can assign a new material to our sprite renderers for the character's sprite(s) (this will also work if you have a multi sprite character like a Spine / Puppet 2D animated character), using a shader like the one below:

```
Shader "Unlit/WorldspaceBlend"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        // Add a texture field for our overlay image.
        _Overlay("Overlay", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    }
    SubShader
    {
        // Duplicate normal sprite shader behaviours.
        // (I skipped implementing pixel snap / split alpha though)
        Tags
        {
            "Queue" = "Transparent"
            "IgnoreProjector" = "True"
            "RenderType" = "Transparent"
            "PreviewType" = "Plane"
            "CanUseSpriteAtlas" = "True"
        }

        Cull Off
        Lighting Off
        ZWrite Off
        Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float4 color : COLOR;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;              
            };

            struct v2f
            {                
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                fixed4 color : COLOR;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float2 overlayUV : TEXCOORD1;               
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            fixed4 _Color;

            // Allow sampling from the overlay image.
            sampler2D _Overlay;
            float4 _Overlay_ST;


            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                o.color = v.color * _Color;

                // Compute what part of the overlay image we should sample.
                float2 worldPos = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex).xy;                
                o.overlayUV = (worldPos - _Overlay_ST.zw)/_Overlay_ST.xy;               

                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv) * i.color;

                // Sample our overlay image.
                fixed4 overlay = tex2D(_Overlay, i.overlayUV);
                // Blend it with our base image.
                fixed4 output = lerp(col, overlay, overlay.a);
                output.a = col.a;
                // Convert to pre-multiplied alpha, as used by sprite shaders.
                output.rgb *= output.a;

                return output;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

This imitates the standard sprite shader, but adds an "Overlay" texture field you can assign in the material inspector for your black zigzag.

The material's scaling & transform parameters for this texture will determine how large & where it's drawn in worldspace. So, you'll want to add a script that sets the following each frame:

```
Vector4 overlayAlignment = character.transform.position + overlayOffset;

material.SetTextureOffset("_Overlay", overlayAlignment);
```

You can then vary the `overlayOffset` vector to slide your overlay texture around relative to the character's position.

Comment: I think this is close to what I was hoping. The overlay works correctly as in I can set the overlay to a different sprite and move the Game object around and it is obscuring the main sprite with the overlay. I am having issues though adjusting the overlay. Right now it takes up one square on the screen with its edges protruding outward. I also coded the overlay script and adjusting it makes no change. I may be using it incorrectly.

I also wondered if instead of using a texture for the overlay I code use a different mat. I was hoping to dynamically change the overlay textures position

Comment: So you tried using the SetTextureOffset method as instructed above, right?

Comment: I believe so. I have: '    void Start()
    {
        mat = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        Vector4 overlayAlignment = gameObject.transform.position + overlayOffset;

        mat.SetTextureOffset("_Overlay", overlayAlignment);
    }'

The over lap looks as follows and adjusting the offset doesn't effect it. https://imgur.com/a/oN3b340

Comment: And you don't observe that to be changing the overlay's position? It's hard for us to diagnose the issue if you don't describe the symptoms in full.

Comment: Sorry if I am not being clear. Adjusting the Offset does not move or change the overlay at all. And the overlay looks strange. I edited the above comment and added a photo.